# How to pass, encode and decode an object through BinaryWriter

Tags: c#, streaming

assuming I have an object `Student s = new Student();`.

furthermore I have BinaryWriter bw.

How do I encode and decode (on a BinaryReader)   none basic type?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Binary Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4abbf6k0.aspx):

```
IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
formatter.Serialize(bw.BaseStream, s);
```

Make sure that your `Student` type is marked as `[Serializable]`.